# Rotate and crop a svg background with CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have a weird shape svg that I cannot edit, is there a way to rotate and crop a piece of it and use it as a background image with CSS? It doesn't necessarily have to be a background image as long as its location stays intact on mobile.

This is my code:

```
<section id="alert">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h4 class="text-center">Get scholarship alerts by providing your info:</h4>
      <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#alert .container {
  padding-top: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}
#alert {
  background-color: #004976;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#alert::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/SN2.svg);
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

With this Pseudo element it looks okay but it doesn't look like the mockup.

This is how it looks with my code:

[image]

And this is the mockup and how it should look:

[image]

This is the actual SVG file: https://svgshare.com/i/SN2.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this is what I got, I think this is what you want to achieve?
[image]

No change was made in the HTML, the CSS changed like this:

```
#alert .container {
  padding-top: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
}
#alert {
  background-color: #004976;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#alert::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/SN2.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 60px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: scaleY(-1) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Basically I rotated and flipped the `after` pseudo-element and played around with the background (I would imagine a shorthand can be used there)

I also added `overflow: hidden;` to make sure the SVG doesn't go outside the container

You can check out my solution here:  https://jsfiddle.net/h7k2eosx/5/

Note that this can present issues depending on the screen size but this should be enough to get you going I hope :)

If your design allows it you could position the `after` pseudo-element with a fixed position, that would work nicely :)
( like here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltamj8r6/ )

Comment: This is nice, but how do we know the height of alert is 100vh? It's set only to a min-height in #alert. Is there a way to make the width of an element == height of its container for full generality (without JS)?

Comment: Dario, it definitely looks better than my version, so thank you. It does have some height issues though, but the min-height probably won't be an issue in my case since the form in the div will be taller than 400px.. i'll get back to you :)

Comment: Thanks @Marz please let me know if it'll work for you :)

Comment: @AHaworth you are right in what you're saying and that is something that I was thinking myself (width of child = height of parent), but I don't think that is really possible.
I did mention that my solution can have height issues, but I did not want to stray too far from what was needed and assume things.

If this needed to be fully dynamic and resizable and whatever I would actually go about adding the svg as an img tag instead of the background-image of a pseudo-element, I haven't tried that but I bet that that implementation would be much easier and flexible to work with